# magento Source model issue

Tags: magento-1.9

i have upgraded magento 1.5 to 1.9 database it's working fine but when i click on edit products in admin side it is showing below error.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:75:"Source model "jaffiliate/source_eventid" not found for attribute "event_id"";i:1;s:3374:"#0 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "j...')
    #1 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
    #2 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
    #3 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
    #4 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
    #5 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
    #6 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
    #7 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
    #8 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
    #9 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
    #10 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #11 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #12 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
    #13 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #14 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
    #15 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(207): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
    #16 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->newAction()
    #17 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
    #18 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #19 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #20 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #21 /home/halsorutan/public_html/v1.9/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:97:"/v1.9/index.php/admin/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/key/f252ded01f1710f8b0e4828c9a3e3807/";s:11:"script_name";s:15:"/v1.9/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

how to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had a module "Jaffiliate" that you have disabled, but if it has created product attributes that rely on it, these will still stay. If you *do* use the module, re-enabling it should fix it. If not, you want to go to `Manage Attributes > Attributes` and remove the `event_id` attribute.

Comment: delete option is not showing in ** Manage Attributes > Attributes **

Comment: Then they must have added it as a `system` attribute. Your only solution is to delete it directly in the database. **Make a database backup first** then you can run the following: `DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'event_id'`

Comment: I have deleted from database but it's not working.

Comment: Do you still get the same error? Are you sure `event_id` doesn't appear in the list of attributes any more?

Comment: I have deleted in eav_attribute  table only. but i have to delete any other tables.

Comment: No you don't need to, `foreign keys` would automatically delete the other entries.

Comment: then how to rectify this issue.

Comment: I've seen a number of Magento installations without foreign keys from the 1.5 era. Please run the database repair tool downloadable from Magento download area to address any issues, after you restore the backup you made and then delete the attribute again.